# Overlapping address ranges in /proc/.../maps

Tags: android, proc, virtual-memory

On some Android devices (possibly only on Android 10 and newer), looking at `/proc/self/maps`, I observed entries like the following two lines:

```
79cfd4d000-79cfff5000 --xp 0012e000 fd:00 286 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so
79cfd4d000-79d01d8000 --xp 0012e000 fd:00 286 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so
```

What surprised me is that the two ranges overlap. Both start at `79cfd4d000`, but one ends at `79cfff5000` and the other one extends further to `79d01d8000`.

What does it mean to have overlapping address ranges here, and why does this even happen?

Comment: Hmm, this may hold a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59737950/2954288 When you  say „looking at“, how do you look?

Comment: @Harald: That's a very good hint, I think, thank you. I was reading the file using `read` syscalls. Maybe the mapping was growing while I was reading the file.